# Можно ли зарегистрировать BroadcastReceiver в активити без IntentFilter?

Tags: android, java, broadcast-receiver

Можно ли зарегать `BroadcastReceiver` в активити без `IntentFilter`? Чтобы можно было получать все сообщения с любыми `intentFilter`. Т.е. зарегать его командой `registerReceiver(MyRec, null)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зарегать то можно, но беда в том, что при этом `BroadcastReceiver` не будет ничего перехватывать, и единственный способ запуска ресивера будет состоять в том, чтобы его самого запустить врукопашную:

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiverClass.class));
```

Comment: это плохо, ибо мне нужно узнать IntentFilter БД контактов

Comment: Проверил, действительно ничего не ловит(